# idiom for iterating a range of angles in a container?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, geometry

Suppose I have data of 2D lines in the form

```
struct Point { int x, y; };
struct Line {
    Point p1, p2;
    double angle() const { return atan2(p2.y-p1.y, p2.x-p1.x); }
};
```

And I want to store these sorted by angle, which must be in the interval `(-PI, PI]`.

My problem: I want to iterate a range in this container, but allow it to wrap around the ends of the interval. For example "all lines between angles `PI*3/4` to `-PI*3/4`".

To clarify, if I use standard containers like `multimap`, I can't simply do the usual:

```
std::multimap<double, Line> lm;

//insert elements...

auto begin = lm.lower_bound(PI*3/4);
auto end = lm.upper_bound(-PI*3/4);
for(auto & i = begin; i != end; ++i) {  //infinite loop: end is before begin!
    //do stuff with i
}
```

I could hack up a "circularly iterate i" function to take the place of the `++i` in the loop, I guess. But this seems like it should be a common problem, so I'm wondering if there's already an existing idiom to address it?

Comment: You propably need a cyclic iterator like suggested by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1782262/7571258).

Comment: @zett42 Definitely looks useful.  I'll give this a try when I get back on a machine with boost.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is trigonometric approach to solve problems with circular ranges. For range  - normalize its ends (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584625/combine-two-segments-on-the-same-circle-if-they-overlap-or-intersect/40585196#40585196)), and get middle angle and half-angle

```
if range_end < range_start then
   range_end = range_end + 2 * Pi

half = (range_end - range_start) / 2
mid  = (range_end + range_start) / 2
coshalf = Cos(half)
```

Now compare that difference of angle and range middle is lower then half-angle. Cosine solves potential troubles with periodicity, negative values etc.

```
if Cos(angle - mid) >= coshalf then
  angle lies in range
```

Comment: I really like how `cos(angle - mid)` removes the wraparound problem.  I'm slightly concerned about the performance hit from calling cos() on every iteration, but I'll see what my profiler says.  Thanks for the tip!