# taking intersection over a continous range of values in python

Tags: python, algorithm, set, linear-algebra, intersection

I have a domain of values on which I want to take intersection.
for example. 0 <= n1 < 2*pi and -pi <= n2 < pi now the n1 intersection n2 would be [0,pi). The ranges of n1 and n2 can be anything. I want to know if there is an easy way to do this. I am currently using nested if-else to do this. I also want to know if their intersection is null if there is no overlap.

Comment: can you show the code you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you need [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40585196/844416)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In module `sympy` there is a class `Set` and several subclasses, including `Interval`.

```py
from sympy import Interval, Intersection, pi

n1 = Interval.Ropen(0, 2*pi)
n2 = Interval.Ropen(-pi, pi)

n3 = Intersection(n1, n2)

print(n3)
# Interval.Ropen(0, pi)
```

Relevant documentation: [sympy Sets](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html)

Comment: Hi! that was very helpful. Do you know how to access the boundary values?
I tried n3[0] or n3.boundary[0] got error.

Comment: Got it, its n3.args[i]

Answer (score 0):

this is a variant:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Range:
    frm: float
    to: float
    # assert frm <= to


def intersect(ranges):
    if ranges[0].to < ranges[1].frm or ranges[1].to < ranges[0].frm:
        # no overlap
        return None

    return Range(frm=max(ranges[0].frm, ranges[1].frm),
                 to=min(ranges[0].to, ranges[1].to))

print(intersect((Range(frm=0, to=2), Range(frm=-1, to=1))))
# -> Range(frm=0, to=1)
```

i used a `dataclass` in order to make it a bit more clear what is going on here. note that for the `Range` i assume the invariant `frm <= to`.

you can get rid of your nested `if` using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min).